# AdvancedDataGrid SummryRow

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, advanceddatagrid

One update:
I tried using the SummaryRow on the datagrid for its basic functionalities and it is working. Now, I need to embed the text in the summary fields. E.g. If one of my summaryfields returns me the count then it should be able to display 'TOTAL (count)'

Is it possible with the summaryrow?

Also, I need to have the data to be formatted when it is displayed. e.g. %age, like 50%, 0.1%, etc.

Is this also possible?

*Hi,
One quick question. I have an AdvancedDataGrid. I need to add a summaryrow to the grid which will contain SUM/AVERAGE of the respective columns in the ADG. Can anyone point me to some tutorial or any reference where I can learn how to create a summaryrow?
Thanks!*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the simplest and easiest approach I found was having another ADG placed below the existing ADG. The new ADG will act like a summary row and hence will have only one row. After initializing the content ADG, we can render the cells of the summary ADG the way we want. Moreover, we can sync the horizontal scroll of the new summary ADG with the content ADG. so, in all it will actually be seen as the ADG with the summary row

Even though its actually not a summary row and one needs a lot of customizations, it does make sense to use this. :)

Answer (score 0):

The advancedDataGrids introduction from adobe contained a demo, but it doesn't seem to be on the web anymore. Have you tried looking at the SummaryField reference? I haven't used summary fields in a while, but it seemed pretty straightforward.

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/collections/SummaryField.html

This is actually a formatting example, but it contains all the code to create a summary row:

http://www.adobe.com/cfusion/communityengine/index.cfm?event=showdetails&productId=2&postId=11472

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have referred to the same resource before but I am having hard time implementing it in my AdvancedDataGrid. I was wondering if there is any step-by-step tutorial for this.

Comment: oh sure...I'll have a look at it.